# Getting Wilson Primes; wont work?

Tags: java, primes, factorial

so I tried making a java program to get ONLY Wilson primes; which have this characteristic: "{[(n-1)!+1]/n}%n=0". The program kind of works, but it only goes as far as number 13 (another wilson prime is 563 for example) when I input 1000. Here's what I have so far.

```
    package again;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class AGAIN 
    {      
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Write a number.");
            int n = 1;
            long r;
            long g;
            for (long u = lol.nextInt(); u >= n; u--)
            {
                long s = 1;
                for (r = u - 1; r >= 1; r--)
                {
                    s = s * r;
                }
                if ((s + 1) % u == 0)
                {
                    g = (s+1) / u;
                    if (g % u == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.printf(u + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why isn't this showing me any larger numbers? Please help!

(here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZUa5k_VIZg )

Comment: you are most likely having overflow issues. 999! is an astronomical number

Comment: even if im not printing the value (of 999! for example) that's a problem? D: what kind of value could i use to make it work?

Comment: UDATE I tried using double's instead of longs... but for some reason it prints A LOT of numbers that do not satisfy the conditions :|

Answer (score 1):

You are asking your program to compute (for `u == 563`) the quantity 562!, which according to Windows Calculator, is approximately 1.12806 * 10^1303.  That is much too large to fit in a `long`, the maximum value of which is [`9223372036854775807`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE) (about 9 quintillion).

Overflow is occurring, and you are not operating on the number you think your are.  The maximum factorial that can be stored in a `long` without overflow is 20!, which is `2432902008176640000`.  (Computing 21! as a `long` yields `-4249290049419214848`, and the overflow is obvious.)

You need to use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)s to calculate and store a number that huge.

Comment: I tried it but it seems BigInteger is immutable (yes... I'm a noob), so I don't know how I could actually use it if        s        (which is the big number) is not going to be printed or anything... It's just there to do the math.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String runx(BigInteger inval)
    {
        BigInteger theval = inval;
        BigInteger calc = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger total = new BigInteger("0");
        String result = "";
        for (BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE; x.compareTo(theval.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) == -1 ; x = x.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        {
            calc = ((calc.multiply(x.add(BigInteger.ONE))));
            //System.out.println("Loop " + x);
        }


        total = calc.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        if((total.mod(theval).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0))
        {
            if (((total.divide(theval)).mod(theval)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)
            {
                result = theval + " is prime and Wilson";
            }
            else
            {
                result = theval + " is prime");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = theval + " is not prime");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You need to write an explanation in the body of the answer or this could be deleted.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the questions for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.